# list various layer animations keys for ios

Tags: ios, calayer, cabasicanimation

What are various layer animation keys, can anyone please let me know with details and example?please let me know if anything wrong here. please help others in cabasicanimations too.

Comment: Your last question (has the same content with this question) has down voted and closed an hour ago. And now you created it again :D ?

Comment: can you send me link for previous question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203320/this-is-not-questn-please-dont-downvote-its-only-data-to-show-layer-animation

Comment: already removed from my side

Answer (score -1):

```
Here's everything I'm aware of in terms of animatable properties, keyPaths, and key-value coding extensions. CALayer Animatable layer properties -- the other CALayer types below all inherit from CALayer, so these also apply to those:

anchorPoint
backgroundColor
backgroundFilters
borderColor
borderWidth
bounds
compositingFilter
contents
contentsRect
cornerRadius
doubleSided
filters
frame
hidden
mask
masksToBounds
opacity
position
shadowColor
shadowOffset
shadowOpacity
shadowPath
shadowRadius
sublayers
sublayerTransform
transform
zPosition
CAEmitterLayer animatable properties:

emitterPosition
emitterZPosition
emitterSize
CAGradientLayer animatable properties:

colors
locations
endPoint
startPoint
CAReplicatorLayer animatable properties:

instanceDelay
instanceTransform
instanceRedOffset
instanceGreenOffset
instanceBlueOffset
instanceAlphaOffset
CAShapeLayer animatable properties:

fillColor
lineDashPhase
lineWidth
miterLimit
strokeColor
strokeStart
strokeEnd
CATextLayer animatable properties:

fontSize
foregroundColor
CATiledLayer animatable properties:

I feel like tileSize is animatable, but documentation doesn't agree. CATransform3D Key-Value Coding Extensions:

rotation.x
rotation.y
rotation.z
rotation
scale.x
scale.y
scale.z
scale
translation.x
translation.y
translation.z
CGPoint keyPaths:

x
y
CGSize keyPaths:

width
height
CGRect keyPaths:

origin
origin.x
origin.y
size
size.width
size.height
```